# Removing an IOS app from the app store- from an existing user's perspective

Tags: ios, app-store

We are "Removing From Sale" an iOS App currently available on the AppStore.  I am curious how this works from the perspective of people who have downloaded the app.  I assume the previously downloaded App will keep working but is there a way (e.g., via an Upgrade) that we can let people know that App is no longer support and give them the option to remove it?  Are there any best practices when removing an App so you don't piss off people who already use it (given that at some point it will break).

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple AppStore and not about programming.

Comment: Please read [what this site is about](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is to release one more update to the app, notifying the user of the pending removal from sale. You could do this using a UIAlertView on launch, or in any number of ways. You could also update the App Store description to call users' attention to the pending deletion. If you simply remove the app from sale, existing users will keep their copy but will not be notified that it has been removed from sale.